# Morris chart with for looped data

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I have a morris chart in my code. I get data to the chart as following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#month_search").click(function(){
          var month_value = $("#month_value").val();

          $.ajax({
            url: '../../new/seller.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {flag: '4', month_value: month_value},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var data_json = JSON.parse(data);
                  var total_chart = {};
                for(i = 0; i < data_json.RESULT.length; i++){
                    var total_all = parseInt(data_json.RESULT[i].total_cus) + parseInt(data_json.RESULT[i].new_cus);
                     total_chart=
                             [{
        category: data_json.RESULT[i].cat_name,
        value: total_all


    }] ;
}  

  var chart1= Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data:total_chart,
    xkey: 'category',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    labels: ['total customers'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
       });
            },
        });


});
```

});

But when showing the chart, only last category is shown. (there are 10 categories in the loop). 
How to show all these  categories in the chart. Please help.

Comment: If you you haven't found a solution yet, Can you post a sample of your data. It might help in assisting you. And by 10 categories do you mean each category should be represented by a single bar, or you want 10 different bar charts representing each category